# Point arrow to direction the user is facing

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer, android-sensors, android-location

In the Google Maps application, there is a small blue arrow that points in the direction the uses is facing. How can I duplicate this in my app? Please provide sample code.

Comment: What have you tried? The compass seems like it would be handy, but the direction from previous fixes seems best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an app where I had to get direction the device was pointing in. In order to get this value, you have to setup a SensorManager and a SensorListener. Here is the basic code to get it going. You will of course have to do some tweaking based on the declination (difference between true north and magnetic north).

```
mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> mySensors = mySensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //device heading in degrees
        float azimuth = event.values[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, the Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION was deprecated. Now it should use other sensors to get the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Take the course (sonetimes called heading) attribute from the current GPS position.

Comment: Apparently this is called Bearing in the Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()

Comment: @NotMe make sure you do not interchange compass bearing (from compass sensor) with GPS (course/heading). I dont know the Android API. (But for this question, compass bearing is well suitabel too, but GPS heading is more precise that compass for higher speeds.